# How does a rotating black hole look like? How would it be to descend into one?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, visualization, kerr-metric

[This image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BH_LMC.png) from Wikipedia shows how a black hole would look like:

[image: Black hole depiction]

A black circle that acts as a gravitational lens for light rays coming from behind.

How would a [rotating black hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole) look like? How would it look like when viewed from side and when viewed from the top (along its axis of rotation)? If I understand it correctly, withing the ergosphere photons are dragged in the direction of the rotation, and just outside it photons would be still heavily influenced by the rotation.

Also [this video](http://www.deepastronomy.com/travel-to-black-holes.html) descibes in detail how would it be to descend into a black hole. What would be different when descending into a rotating one? In particular, what would we see inside the ergosphere? And how would it be different below the event horizon?

Comment: It would be awesome!

Comment: Anybody who tells you anything about the physics near the event horizon, above or below, is a descendent of the Baron von Munchausen. The trivial answer is that we don't know anything about that regime because we haven't done any measurements, yet.

Comment: @CuriousOne Of course, but we can always deduce some information from our current theoretical knowledge, similarly to gravitational lens being predicted from the theory before being observed.

Comment: Your current theoretical knowledge about the physics near the event horizon is, as I said, next to zero, you are merely extrapolating one possible physical theory that agrees with low field data beyond the limits of experimental tests and you call that "knowledge". The best we really have, right now, are probably a few ideas about the physics at the surface of neutron stars, which, I believe, would be at about four times the Schwarzschild radius.